# Underwater Civilisation warfare

Tags: weapons, aliens, underwater

I'm interested in finding out, for a humanoid civilisation that develops underwater (with gills), how would they develop the equivalent of a modern-day assault rifle, with a minimum effective range of 100 metres? What would they use to to "propel" the projectile and how would they stop/overcome the drag? How would they develop the materials?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Of course the bot makes a valid point. We don't know exactly what you need. But some suggestions for clarifying the question could revolve around say speed and distance of sound travelling in a fluid, so to do with stealth. Another angle is viscosity under water which limits propulsion systems. And further whether there's any considerations around the electrical conductivity of the fluid. But you'll have to pick one to focus on and take the problem solving approach a step at a time. :-)

Comment: Aside from that, perhaps a good direction to help get your ideas flowing is to look at how animals have evolved systems which help them cope with life under water. Such as the explosive kinetic force of the mantis shrimp, bioluminescent lures, cephalopod camouflage, animal language and communications ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tUXbbbMhvk ), etc.

Comment: @Nolo sorry I'm still new here, how do I clarify? I just want to know some ideas for weapons, any and all. Edit: Do I have to be specific with what weapons I want?

Comment: No worries. It's simply a matter of choosing any hypothetical kind of weapon, only one, and ask about that. Then, however that helps, move on to another kind of weapon and just ask as many questions as you need as long as each is focused to a single kind of problem. Be sure also to try to find specific answers which relate to your specific questions before asking the same ones that have already been asked. :-)

Comment: We don't really have a scoped way of addressing more general kinds of questions, so the top down view of what a military looks like is kinda off the table. You have to reason about that over the sum of it's parts, which we _can_ help you determine if you manage to focus on your parts and get satisfactory answer on them.

Comment: This is soooo going to get closed for being too broad and not enough detail. For starters - what is your Civilization? Are they Humans? Humanoid? Do they breath Air? Do they have Gills? Can they withstand oceanic pressures? What are their Pain tolerances like? What is their weaknesses? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @TheDemonLord I tried to edit the question. Can you let me know if i need to edit it again

Comment: I think your new version is better excepted you should reserve the conception of the materials for another question, after this one and after you thought about it more. There's an incredible amount of issues with making land technology in water, namely good heating and avoiding water interfering with components (e.g.: chemicals concentration losses, unwanted reactions...). It's extremely hard to mimicry land designs underwater and achieve the same results. Normally you adapt your tools to the environment, not the other way round.

Comment: Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2):

Okay - so, you want an under-water assault rifle?

Using existing tech, we do have Supercavitating ammunition that is effective out to 60 metres underwater: [Details here](https://newatlas.com/military/dsg-cavx-supercavitating-underwater-bullets/)

But 60 metres isn't 100.

However - that is predicated on essentially retro-fitting an existing Rifle with special ammunition. I don't think an Underwater civilization would have evolved their weapons systems from gunpowder firearms (for obvious reasons)

More likely, their evolution would start out with a Spear Gun. Probably powered by some form of elastic material (similar to a crossbow), eventually getting to a point of using compressed Air (or other gas) to propel the projectile - but a Spear Gun is only good for up to 10 metres (absolute best case scenario).

There are a few factors that we can consider:

Modern Firearms are designed to be reasonably light (not too light, recoil impulse is a thing) - because humping a rifle through the Jungle/Desert/Urban environment sucks.

However, an underwater weapon could be made neutrally bouyant, so there is much less fatigue in carrying it. Now, sure you wouldn't want it to be super-heavy - as inertia and momentum are a thing - but it also means you can make it bigger, with bigger projectiles and it not be a significant negative.

This allows you to have a bigger projectile and more importantly...

**It allows for self-propelling projectiles**

In short, you're firing mini-torpedoes.

This is where I'd start. Something like a 40mm grenade launcher type system, that fires a long slender mini-torpedo, with a small propellant charge.